# If $\sum_{n \geq 1}a_{n}$ converges, and $a_{n} > 0$ , then...

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it true or false that if $\sum_{n \geq 1}a_{n}$ converges, and $a_{n} > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a_{n+1} \leq a_{n}$ for all $n \geq k$ ?

I think that it's true because  $a_{n} \to 0$ (when $n \to \infty$) and also $(a_{n})$ is positive, so there must be a point from where $(a_{n})$ is monotonicly decreasing...

But it sounds too simple so I'm not sure...

Comment: It's tempting to think so, but this is unfortunately not true, say for example $a_{2n}=2^{-n}$ and $a_{2n+1}=0$.

Comment: @JoelCohen: The OP wants $a_n > 0 \ \forall n$.

Comment: Just to give an example with all positive entries:  suppose $a_{2n}=\frac 1{n^2}$ and $a_{2n+1}=\frac 2{n^2}$.

Comment: @Alex M. Ah yes sorry, take $a_{2n +1}=3^{-n}$ then.

Comment: Ohh because of discontinuity... So it's false

Comment: @Lisa It has nothing to do with discontinuity.  But yes, it's false.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $a_n = \left( \frac 1 3 \right)^n$ and $b_n = \left( \frac 1 2 \right)^n$, and the series

$$a_1 + b_1 + a_2 + b_2 + a_3 + b_3 + \dots = \sum _{n \ge 1} c_n$$

where $c_n = \begin{cases} a_{\frac {n+1} 2}, & n \text{ odd} \\ b_{\frac n 2}, & n \text{ even} \end{cases}$. The series is absolutely convergent.

Notice that $c_{2k-1} = a_k = \left( \frac 1 3 \right)^k \le \left( \frac 1 2 \right)^k = c_{2k}$, but $c_{2k} = \left( \frac 1 2 \right)^k \ge \left( \frac 1 3 \right)^{k+1} = c_{2k+2}$.

A more complicated example: $\sum \Bbb e^{-n} (1 + \sin n)$ - again, absolutely convergent, but with "oscillating terms".